# zsh: `declare -p` associative array does not print values

Tags: zsh, associative-array

`run-help typeset` says:

> ```
>   -p [ n ]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
>           If  the  -p  option  is  given, parameters and values are                                                                                                                                            
>           printed in the form of a typeset command with an  assign-                                                                                                                                            
>           ment,  regardless  of other flags and options.  Note that                                                                                                                                            
>           the -H flag on parameters is respected; no value will  be                                                                                                                                            
>           shown for these parameters.
> ```

Note it says `parameters and values` above.

If it do:

```
% typeset -p ZPLGM 
typeset -A ZPLGM
```

Note no key-values above, however they do exist:

```
% echo $ZPLGM[PLUGINS_DIR]
/home/ravi/.config/zsh/.zplugin/plugins
```

1. Why doesn't `typeset -p` work as I expect?
2. How do I get `typeset` to print a statement which, when executed, would recreate the array?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing using two shells, zsh and bash? First, zsh doesn't have a `help` command, in `oh-my-zsh`, `help` is an alias of `man`. `help typeset` will show an error. Second, maybe you run `typeset -p ZPLGM` in bash, but run `echo` command in zsh.

Comment: @Feng It's definitely `zsh`. I updated the question to `run-help`: `run-help is a shell function from /usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help`.  This resolves to `less /usr/share/zsh/5.5.1/help/declare`

Comment: `declare -A foo; foo[bar]=a; foo[baz]=b; declare -p foo` prints `typeset -A foo=( [bar]=a [baz]=b )` for me in zsh  5.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variable `ZPLGM` is defined with `-H` option.

```
unset foo
typeset -AH foo=([bar]=123)
#         ^----here
echo $foo[bar]
typeset -p foo
```

> ```
> 123
> typeset -A foo
> ```

`typeset` has an option `-H`, as the manual explains:

> ```
>   -H     Hide  value:  specifies that typeset will not display the
>          value of the parameter when listing parameters; the  dis-
>          play for such parameters is always as if the `+' flag had
>          been given.  Use of the parameter is  in  other  respects
>          normal, and the option does not apply if the parameter is
>          specified by name, or by  pattern  with  the  -m  option.
>          This   is  on  by  default  for  the  parameters  in  the
>          zsh/parameter and zsh/mapfile  modules.   Note,  however,
>          that  unlike the -h flag this is also useful for non-spe-
>          cial parameters.
> ```

```
unset foo
typeset -A foo=([bar]=123)
echo $foo[bar]
typeset -p foo
```

> ```
> 123
> typeset -A foo=( [bar]=123 )
> ```